# Java: Insert scores into remote MySQL database without hardcoding login credentials

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm writing a small game in Java and I want to save user scores into a remote MySQL database. I'm using JDBC right now and I've got the connection working. I can insert and read as desired. The login credentials are hardcoded right now though:

```
public class DatabaseHandler {
    private final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://_ip_goes_here_:3306/";
    private final String DB_NAME = "db_name";
    private final String USERNAME = "username";
    private final String PASSWORD = "password";

    //Rest of class
}
```

I can imagine that one could easily decompile the class file and extract this Information, thus gaining the ability to write into the database as they see fit.

Is there a better option to archive connection or would you use some kind of middleman between the .jar and the database? How would one realize this?

Comment: This is a duplicate question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381366/how-to-hide-password-to-mysql-database-from-people-using-the-program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of thing is where a properties file comes in handy.  This page has examples on both reading and writing those, incidentally with the kind of parameters that you're dealing with:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Hopefully that amount of separation is sufficient for your needs.

Comment: How is this any different from hardcoding the login credentials? Isn't the property file just as easy to read as the class file?

Comment: You have to put the credentials somewhere, unless you're going to manually enter them every time. Aside from doing things directly with the database, you can also set up a client and server situation using SOAP or some other protocol on top of HTTP. You'll probably still need to have authentication of some kind, but you can limit what can be done to the database by the game code.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to build a webservice to act as the middleman then.

Comment: I've been looking all over and everything I've found seems really complex. Is it really that hard or am I not searching hard enough? Could you maybe point me to a good tutorial?

Comment: A quick Google search turns up a list of them. I don't know which ones would be better for your situation: https://www.google.com/search?q=web+service+client+server+java+example

Answer (score 0):

Totaly agree with  Brian - properties are not compiled into your .jar/.war/.ear - you can change them as you wish whenever necessary, that is the biggest plus of using them